# How to get rid of the ceiling function on one side of an equation

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Given this function,

$\left\lceil \log _{b-1} \left(\lceil \frac{1}{b} \rceil\right) \right\rceil=1$

How do I get rid of the ceiling function so I can obtain the value of $B$ ?

Comment: Try writing this in mathematical notation, maybe someone will understand it then: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The statements $\lceil x \rceil=n$ and $n-1 < x \le n$ (where $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$) are equivalent.

Comment: Now that someone has edited the question, is the equation correct? I don't think it has a solution as written.

Comment: see the comment that I left after Ross Millikan's answer.

Comment: My apologies. The actual equation is Given this function,

⌈log−1(⌈106812/⌉)⌉=1

Comment: Re your last comment, which is much more recent than the last editing on your query, do you mean $$\left\lceil \log_{(b-1)} \left( \left\lceil \frac{106812}{b}\right\rceil\right) \right\rceil = 1?$$

Comment: Assuming that the above comment is accurate: please consider the following two criticisms, for other queries that you will be posting on mathSE: [1] -1 (downvote) to your query because you never proofread your query against your understanding of what the problem is supposed to be and because after making your comment above, you did not go back and edit your query [2] As a point of reference, I formatted the above comment via `$$\left\lceil \log_{(b-1)} \left( \left\lceil \frac{106812}{b}\right\rceil\right) \right\rceil = 1?$$`.

Answer (score 1):

If $b \lt 0$ the ceiling of $\frac 1b$ is at most $0$ and the log is undefined.  If $b \ge 1$ the ceiling of $\frac 1b$ is $1$ and the log is $0$, which fails, so we have $0 \lt b \lt 1$.  In that case $b-1 \lt 0$.  The definition I know for logs to a base different from $e$ is $\log_a(x)=\frac {\log x}{\log a}$.  If $b-1 \lt 0, \log_{b-1}x$ is undefined and there is no answer.

Comment: In the spirit of moving targets, I started to consider attacking the separate problem of $$\left\lceil \log _{b-1} \left|\lceil \frac{1}{b} \rceil\right| \right\rceil=1.$$  But the only way the change is pertinent is if $b < 0 \implies (b-1) < 0$, so (again) $\log_{b-1} x$ is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $x\le \lceil x\rceil<x+1$; therefore $\lceil y\rceil = N$ is equivalent to $N-1< y\le N$.

Comment: ack, yep, double typo. thanks

Comment: So, how does it feel, trying to hit a moving target?